# PHP - Array_diff with two arrays with different dimension

Tags: php, arrays, search, multidimensional-array, array-difference

I have this 2 arrays:

```
$haystack = array("rowid" => array("100", "200"), "description" => array ("something", "something else"));
$needle = array("rowid" => array("200", "300", "400"), "description" => array ("something else", "other", "other else"), "test" => "bye");
```

I want to do an array_diff with $needle and $haystack but i get an error because $needle array is multidimensional but "test" key has got only one dimension:

```
foreach ($needle as $key => $value) :
$left[$key] = array_diff($needle[$key],$haystack[$key]);
endforeach;
```

> Warning: array_diff(): Argument #1 is not an array 
> Warning:
>   array_diff(): Argument #2 is not an array

How can i solve the problem?
I need to maintain in $left array only "rowid" and "description" values (i can discard "test" value).

$left should be:

```
Array
(
    [rowid] => Array
        (
            [0] => 300
            [1] => 400
        )

    [description] => Array
        (
            [0] => other
            [1] => other else
        )

)
```

Thank you for help!

Comment: You loop through your array and try to `array_diff` every element. But our last `test`-value is no array. So you get a warning. Check the element before you pass it to the function with `is_array()`

Answer (score 0):

remove  "test" => "bye"; from $needle or write them proper way.

```
//array_diff takes arguments as array.
foreach ($needle as $key => $value) :
$left[$key] = array_diff($needle[$key],$haystack[$key]);
//when $key = test $needle[$key]=bye which is not array 
//thats why you got Warning: array_diff(): Argument #1 is not an array  this warning

//again when $key=test ,$haystack[$key]=null which is not array
//thats why you got Warning: array_diff(): Argument #2 is not an array
endforeach;
```

Comment: OK. But if i don't know how many "test" or other key is in $needle array? How can i filter only "rowid" and "description" keys? Thank you!